# creating vector using templates in cpp

Tags: c++, templates

This is example from a text book. We are creating vector using templates. in main function we copy the predefined array into vectors. Finally, we multiply two vectors. Although program compiles nicely the program fails to execute. Whats wrong with the code.

```
#include <iostream>

const int size = 3;

template<class T>
class vector
{
    T* v;
public:
    vector()
    {
        v = new T[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            v[i] = 0;
        }
    }

    vector(const T* a)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            v[i] = a[i];
        }
    }

    T operator * (const vector& y)
    {
        T sum = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            sum += this->v[i] * y.v[i];
        }
        return sum;
    }
};

int main()
{
    int x[3] = { 1, 2, 3 };
    int y[3] = { 4, 5, 6 };
    vector<int> v1;
    vector<int> v2;
    v1 = x;
    v2 = y;
    int R = v1 * v2;
    std::cout << R;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What exactly fails? What are your errors? Also, be careful with `using namespace std;` That namespace already contains `vector`. You should use `std::` instead, as in `std::cout`.

Comment: If that is an example from a textbook, and you didn't forget anything while typing it - drop that textbook and find a better one. The code is terrible.

Comment: Welcome to SO:SE. Have you tried something to understand the reason?

Comment: `v` is uninitialized when you try to put elements in it in constructor `vector(T *a)`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all in this constructor

```
   vector(T *a)
  {
      for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
         v[i]= a[i];
     }
  }
```

you did not allocate the array pointed to by v. Pointer v is not initialized. So the constructor has undefined behaviour.

And another potential problem is that you did not define the copy assignment operator.

In these statements

```
v1 = x; v2 = y;
```

temporary objects of type vector are created and after the assignment they will be deleted. Thus the new created objects will have invalid pointer v.

You have to define at least copy constructor, copy assignment operator and destructor.